biometric web authentication js
How to implement biometric web  authentication in JavaScript web applications.
I ran my web application on an Android device, but encountered an error stating 'passkey not available. where store credential in android device.

how about https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/11/16/biometric-authentication-for-web-devs/ ?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
